# "the method ** is undefined for the type string" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, undefined

I am currently completing a project and am trying to create a menu. The menu itself works alright but when I try and link to the other java file that the method itself is in I get the error "the method *method name* is undefined for the type String". Below is the code that I am using to try and link to the method in the other java file.

```
        {
        if (menuChoice.equals("A"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Movie ID: ");
            movieID = sc.nextLine();
            movieID.borrowMovie();
        }
        if (menuChoice.equals("a"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Movie ID: ");
            movieID = sc.nextLine();
            movieID.borrowMovie();
        }
        if (menuChoice.equals("B"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Movie ID: ");
            movieID = sc.nextLine();
            movieID.returnMovie();
        }
        if (menuChoice.equals("b"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Movie ID: ");
            movieID = sc.nextLine();
            movieID.returnMovie();
        }
```

Further to, below is the code of the 2 methods that I am trying to link to in the other java file. It is a requirement of the project to have 2 separate class files and to demonstrate how to use them both together but this part has got me stumped!

```
// Implement borrowMovie method
public double borrowMovie(String memberID)
{
    if (this.isOnLoan = false)
    {
        this.isOnLoan = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    }

// Implement returnMovie method
public double returnMovie(int daysBorrowed)
{
    if (this.isOnLoan = false)
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        this.isOnLoan = false;

    }
}
```

Any help at all will be appreciated :)

Comment: What's the **exact** error? Also please note that `if (this.isOnLoan = false)` is assigning `false` to `isOnLoan` and the whole expression is evaluated to **false**, always. You should use `==` (Or (better) `if (!this.isOnLoan)`).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: compiler errors don't have a stacktrace. And `if (!this.isOnLoan)` is preferrable over boolean comparison.

Comment: @jlordo I didn't notice that's a compiler error. And of course it's preferable, I just wanted him to know that `==` is for equality.

Comment: `sc.nextLine()` returns a `String`, and you are invoking `movieID.borrowMovie();` on that. That's plain wrong. We could help more, if you can show exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your code, I guess that `movieID` is a `String`.

Class `String` does not have methods `borrowMovie()` and `returnMovie()`, so you'll get an error from the compiler that tells you so.

Instead of `movieID.borrowMovie()` you want: `borrowMovie(movieID)`.

Here's another bug in your `borrowMovie()` and `returnMovie()` methods:

```
if (this.isOnLoan = false)
```

You are **assigning** the value `false` to `this.isOnLoan` here. That is most likely not what you want. Use `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment. Better yet, to check if a `boolean` is `false`, use `!`:

```
if (!this.isOnLoan)
```

Why are your methods returning `double` values?

Answer (score 0):

This line assigns the value false to isOnLoan and as such will always yield true.

if (this.isOnLoan = false)

Apart from this there's no return value on the else branch for example:

```
public double returnMovie(int daysBorrowed)
{
    if (this.isOnLoan = false)
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        this.isOnLoan = false;
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to return a Double value on the else branch

public double returnMovie(int daysBorrowed)
{
    if (this.isOnLoan = false)
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        this.isOnLoan = false;
return this.id;
    }
}