# the method is undefined for the type string

Tags: java, string

why would I have "the method is undefined for the type string" in java with this statement:

```
if(book.getTitle().getAuthor().getAward()){..}
```

the error is for getAward()

when I have defined a class Author as this:

```
class Author {

private String name;
private boolean award;
public Author(String n, boolean p){
    name=n;
    award=p;
}

public String getName(){return name;}
public boolean getAward(){return award;}
```

}
May the error come from another definition (other than Author?)

Comment: What does `getTitle()` return? What does `getAuthor()` return?

Comment: getAuthor() returns a string and not an Author object.

Comment: isn't this duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810669/the-method-is-undefined-for-the-type-string-in-eclipse

Comment: actually get Author is in another class and returns a string. getTitle is from a third class and returns string as well. Book is from a fourth class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> actually get Author is in another class and returns a string. getTitle is from a third class and returns string as well. Book is from a fourth class.

Then the answer is obvious.

You are attempting to call `getAuthor()` on the result of calling `getTitle()`.  But the result of `getTitle()` is a `String` ... and `String` doesn't have a `getAuthor()` method.

And that is exactly what the compilation error is telling you.

---

In fact, you probably should write:

```
if(book.getAuthor().getAward()){..}
```

then change `getAuthor()` to return the `Auteur` object ... rather than the author's name.

A book (Oevre) has an author, but a title (String) does not.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you please look to the entire code that I have just posted as an answer to my own question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your `getAuthor()` method implementation to that

```
public Author getAuthor(){
   return new Author(); // or some author that is set in your object
}
```

And on that you can performe another method.
`if(book.getTitle().getAuthor().getAward())` if Author class have method `getAward`

```
public class Author{
  public boolean getAward(){ // implementation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `getAuthor` method to

```
public Author getAuthor(){
  return author;
}
```

and if you want the `authors` `award`, then u should invoke

`book.getAuthor().getAward()`